# Non-static method Bogardo\Mailgun\Mailgun::send() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: php, laravel-5, mailgun

Hi I am using bogard/mailgun library to send email
I have followed steps from 
https://packagist.org/packages/bogardo/mailgun

following code I have called in controller

```
Mailgun::send('emails.welcome', $data, function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

Error showing from above code 
`Non-static method Bogardo\Mailgun\Mailgun::send() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

Here send function's code

```
namespace Bogardo\Mailgun;

use Bogardo\Mailgun\Mailgun\Lists;
use Bogardo\Mailgun\Mailgun\MailgunApi;
use Bogardo\Mailgun\Mailgun\Message;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\View\Factory;

class Mailgun extends MailgunApi
{

    /**
     * Send a new message.
     *
     * @param string|array   $view
     * @param array          $data
     * @param Closure|string $callback
     * @param bool           $mustInit
     *
     * @return object Mailgun response containing http_response_body and http_response_code
     */
    public function send($view, array $data, $callback, $mustInit = true)
    {
        if ($mustInit) {
            $this->_init();
        }

        $this->callMessageBuilder($callback, $this->message);

        $this->getMessage($view, $data);

        return $this->mailgun(true, config('mailgun.api_key'))->sendMessage(config('mailgun.domain'), $this->getMessageData(), $this->getAttachmentData());
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you need an instance of mailgun and then you can use "non-static" methods... and Laravel-5.3 supports Mailgun out of the box... `Supported: "smtp", "mail", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses", "sparkpost", "log"` info can be found at `config/mail.php`

Comment: yes its sent emails but it won't return response eg: email sent ID for tracking email, that's why I am using it for tracking emails.

Comment: Can you show the `use` statements at the top of the class where you're using `Mailgun::send`.

Comment: yea already defined `use Bogardo\Mailgun\Mailgun`